# How to fix npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting on Github action

Tags: git, github, npm, github-actions

However, there was no problem on my local machine, but when I tried to run it on Github Action, it returned the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting circomlib@git+ssh://git@github.com/iden3/circomlib.git#01da5f90dbbefeed5d78cec3b87303244338b920:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting circomlib@git+ssh://git@github.com/iden3/circomlib.git#01da5f90dbbefeed5d78cec3b87303244338b920:
npm ERR! sha512-OF64V7dfbkj1osftTsCNzaVNLeFK2uJgbSc3biwNEBaXzDnVdFonWZIBEe5LITF7rUU2NuAmNxZkseOqZsxbaw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-OF64V7dfbkj1osftTsCNzaVNLeFK2uJgbSc3biwNEBaXzDnVdFonWZIBEe5LITF7rUU2NuAmNxZkseOqZsxbaw== but got sha512-YpCfcBsDUI8PiHjXqZPt6zfZua22FDZ4+mJuMse8Je1i0Ju3lfooVesNOVbSguQB0Qs5ndSyNHbHTWcZIOoh1A==. (374114 bytes)
```

Also here is my .yml file

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [11.x, 12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Setup node-version ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
    - name: git config
      run: |
        git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com
    - name: NPM install and prepare
      run: |
        npm ci
        // some tests
        // ...
```

It's the first time I've seen this error and I couldn't find any answers to it in my research, so I'd like to ask for help from anyone who has any idea what's going on.

Comment: The `Verification failed` error means that as far as NPM could tell from authoritative sources, the version of the code it got from `git@github.com/iden3/circomlib.git` has been tampered with. I'm not an NPM expert so I'm not sure where it gets its authoritative signatures but `https://registry.npmjs.org` seems a likely candidate. The question then becomes: *did* someone tamper with the *repository*, or did someone tamper with or goof up the *signature?*

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understand how it works however still this error doesn't make sense. I've changed the module "resolved" data from `"resolved": "git+ssh://git@github.com/{...}` to `"resolved": "git+https://github.com/{...}"` with the same sha512 hash, the error gone.

Comment: That's definitely weird. I wonder if something has gone wrong with ssh access such that the `#<hash>` part got cut off and you got the wrong *commit* delivered. The https access encodes the `#` so that the hash ID does not get cut off. That's just a guess, though.

Comment: What does the entry for `circomlib` in your `package.json` file look like?